# Some sort of boot menu, possibly the gnu menu

Tags: boot, systemd

So I tried to factory reset my other computer (wich uses ubuntu) thru reinstalling ubuntu with  a usb, and after spamming all the f1-f9 keys to try to get into the boot menu it put me on black screen with code, at the  end it says ''A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (31min 10s / no limit)''

I have tried to restart the computer but it directly send me to this, unofortunatly i can't post a picture since the computer with the problem I can't use and a picture from my phone would be above 2mib. however i can write some of the code here if needed.

And sorry if the terms are not correct since I am a pretty new ubuntu user.

Edit: After looking on google I found people talking about accessing the Grub menu however that is something I can't access, doesn't matter how much I click shift and esc.

Edit 2: so i started to dwonload ubuntu on  a usb and try to download ubuntu again, I turned of the computer then I turned it on, and as it seems it fixed itself! If you are wondering I had about 2hr 30min of the ''A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (x min x s / no limit)''

Comment: Did you install it already or are you trying to start from the usb stick?

Comment: I tried to get into the boot menu and had the usb stick in the coommputer.